# how to call a function stored in an array

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this simple example that works

```
const func1 = function (i) { return (i) }
const func2 = function (i) { return (i * 2) }
const func3 = function (i) { return (i * 3) }
const func4 = function (i) { return (i * 4) }
const funcs = ['func1', 'func2', 'func3', 'func4']

function myFunction() {

  let item = 3
  let i = 2
  let result = eval(`${funcs[item]}(${i})`)
  console.log(result)
  // what about call_user_func in google app script

}
```

Since eval() is not recommended, what will be the google app script equivalent of call_user_func (php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with Google Apps Script but in standard JS you should just be able to call it like `let result = funcs[item](i);`

For this you also need to put your actual function variables into the array, like
`const funcs = [func1, func2, func3, func4]`, not like `const funcs = ['func1', 'func2', 'func3', 'func4']`

Functions are first-class citizens in JS, which means you can pass them around and call them like any other variable

Comment: I have tried so many ways! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Accept the answer if you like it :)

JavaScript is a weird beast but pretty cool when you get the right mindset for it

Answer (score 1):

#### In google apps script you can also call functions by name

```
function executeFunctionByName(func) {
  this[func]();
}
```

Comment: Thx Cooper ... Something weird: it's ok if I write the function as follows `function myFunc(x) { Browser.msgBox(x * 2); }`, and it doesn't work if function is written as `const myFunc = function (x) { Browser.msgBox(x * 2) }`! Do you have an explanation?

Comment: What does that have to do with my answer?

Comment: I tried your suggestion. Unfortunately, I couldn't achieve the expected result with my definition of the functions (see the posted request) until I changed them. That's all! But I also remember this one. Upvoted.

Comment: I run all kinds of functions this way all of the time.  I search for them in my new development files and load them into a drop down in my side bar thus allowing me to easily run new functions from the sidebar.